# Nio bytebuffers (by channel) against IO BufferInputStream

Tags: java, io, nio

Which of the two would be the best choice and in which circumstance?
Clearly there is no sense in using a file channel for a very small file. Besides that, what are the pro and cons of the two input/output means.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FileChannel has many features missing in java.io: it is interruptible, it can move position within the file, it can lock a file, etc. And it can be faster than old IO, especially when it uses direct byte buffers, here is an explanation from ByteBuffer API:

```
byte buffer is either direct or non-direct. Given a direct byte buffer, the Java virtual machine will make a best effort to perform native I/O operations directly upon it. That is, it will attempt to avoid copying the buffer's content to (or from) an intermediate buffer before (or after) each invocation of one of the underlying operating system's native I/O operations.
```

If you need none of the above features go with streams, you'll get a shorter code.

Comment: Bottom line: besides the direct memory access, and not considering the interruptible thing it is the same?

Comment: Yes, if you want just to read a file content, speed not critical, the result will be the same. FileChannel has 2 disadvantages - peoople rarely use it and it can work only with bytes, while every programmer knows streams and streams can be used to read text.

Comment: regarding the bytes thing. it can still be converted in a CharBuffer by the Charset class.

Comment: i agree, but there will be difficulties reading text line by line